# What does Viktor yell in Yuri On Ice?

Tags: japanese-language, yuri-on-ice

Is he yelling "kusnav" or like "kusnov"?

What does it even mean ... couldn't find anything on the webs - am I heavily mistyping it?

Comment: it sounds Russian which [according to this answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/39086/1587) Yuri and Victor are both based off Russians not to mention that Victor in the anime is Russian anyway. i would suspect that it's actually Russian. as for any mistyping when i google them i get google trying to correct me with *"kushnav"* but having not seen the series i'm not sure if this is correct or not

Comment: @Memor-X: FWIW I don't think "kushnav" ever appears in the series.

Comment: It would greatly help if you would indicate the place of the supposed appearance of this word. ie timing, episode number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only similar-sounding word that I recall hearing in *Yuri!!! on Ice* is the *Russian* word *vkusno* ([вкусно](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE)), which in the show is sometimes used by characters to mean "tasty". (For instance, it appears in ep. 2 when Victor is introduced to [katsudon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katsudon), and when in ep. 9, Yuri Katsuki tastes the katsudon [pirozhki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirozhki) that  Yuri Plisetsky's grandfather made.)

The IPA transcription of вкусно is [ˈfkusnə]: it is then not implausible that a casual listener might miss the initial [f] sound or be confused when transcribing the final [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa), leading to a transcription like *kusna* or *kusno*. (When encountering unexpected two consonant combinations, I have sometimes missed the first consonant entirely: for instance, when I first heard the Hebrew song "Hatikvah", I heard "tsofiyah" (צופיה) as "sofiyah," because it was easier for me to process what I heard that way when I was not listening carefully.)

Answer (score 0):

Viktor Nikiforov yells the word 'Vkusno' (вкусно), which is the Russian word for 'delicious'. If you notice, he only yells it when eating Pork Cutlet Bowls (not a euphemism) and Hot Pot!!